# Is there a more concise way to format .expect() message?

Tags: rust, format

I currently have to use this to format a `.expect()` message:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: Option<&str> = None;
    x.expect(&format!("the world is ending: {}", "foo")[..]);
}
```

Is there a less verbose way?

Comment: you don't need `[..]`

Comment: `expect()` is a "quick and dirty" way to discard option, you are not really expected to use it to create accurate error. so generally just `"that should not happen"` is enough

Comment: @Stargateur about "that should not happen": What am i supposed to use when i whant to panic if result is an error ?

Comment: `Option::expect` is basically [panic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libcore/option.rs#L1037) when x is `None`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you don't need to write `[..]`

---

If you really want to panic but also want to format the error message, I think I would use [`assert!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: Option<&str> = None;
    assert!(x.is_some(), "the world is ending: {}", "foo");
    let _x = x.unwrap();
}
```

---

If you want you could also use the [`unwrap`](https://crates.io/crates/unwrap) crate:

```rust
use unwrap::unwrap;

fn main() {
    let x: Option<&str> = None;
    let _x = unwrap!(x, "the world is ending: {}", "foo");
}
```

---

Also, both these methods avoid the construction of the error `String` every time, unlike calling `expect()` with `format!()`.

Answer (score 59):

I would do:

```rust
option.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("ah: {}", "nuts"))
```

This is for `Option`, for `Result` you need to ignore the argument:

```rust
result.unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("ah: {}", "nuts"))
```

Formatting a string is somewhat costly. This will avoid formatting the string unless it is really needed.

Comment: Just came here to say that as of September 2022, `cargo clippy --fix` performs this exact conversion automatically: 

`option.expect(&format!("ah: {}", "nuts"));`

becomes:

`option.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("ah: {}", "nuts"));`

Comment: The closure takes an argument, so `|_| panic!("ah: {}", "nuts")`

Comment: Closure argument isn't needed for Option's unwrap_or_else: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the unnecessary overhead of formatting and allocating a `String` in the case of an `Ok`, you can convert the `Option` to a `Result` and then unwrap it:

```
fn main() {
    let x: Option<&str> = None;
    x.ok_or_else(|| format!("the world is ending: {}", "foo"))
        .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: What about `Result`?

Comment: @ErdinEray I don't understand your question - `ok_or_else` returns a `Result`.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't make myself clear. `x` is an `Option<&str>` and `Option` has `ok_or_else` method, yet I cannot seem to find a similar method for `Result` (like, "run this closure in case of an `Error`"). I know this can be done with `match`, but I'd like to panic with a detailed (formatted) error message in a closure I provide to `Result`. `expect` for `Result` does not take a `closure`, it takes a `&str`.

Comment: @ErdinEray What about `result.map_err()`? Or `result.ok().ok_or_else()`

Comment: Don't bother creating a `Result` if you're just going to immediately `unwrap` it.