# expect with prinln!()-style arguments?

Tags: rust, panic

I'm using code such as:

```
OpenOptions::new().write(true)
                  .read(true)
                  .create_new(true)
                  .open(&file_b).expect(&format!("cannot open {:?}", &file_b))
```

Is there a shorter way to write `.expect(&format!("cannot open {:?}", &file_b))`?

(I've tried `.expect("cannot open {:?}", &file_b)`, but `.expect()` requires just one argument.)

I would also like to avoid the cost of `format!` when there is no error.

---

Update: Following @Aloso's comment, I looked at "anyhow".

This code:

```
let mut file_a = OpenOptions::new().write(args.file_b.is_none())
                                   .read(true)
                                   .open(&args.file_a)
                                   .with_context(|| format!("Error opening {}", args.file_a))?;
```

produces this error:

```
Error: Error opening foo.txt

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

which is exactly what I want.

Comment: @kmdreko no, these are `expect()` calls on `Option<>`, rather than on files.  No answers there are significantly more concise.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291643/129805 is interesting and may provide the implementation for me to write a custom `expect!()` macro,  It illustrates the important point that I should only invoke the cost of `format!` when the code has failed.

Comment: In the past, [the feature was proposed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1968) but closed. Reasons are already stated as above.

Comment: `.expect()` on `Option`s and `Result`s (which `.open()` returns) are functionally equivalent in this regard. And the lack of concise answers is an answer itself. A primary issue is macro syntax allows variable arguments but methods do not. There's an RFC for [postfix macros](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2442) that could allow things like `.expect!("{}", ...)` though I don't know if/when that will land.

Comment: The best solution at the moment is `.unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("cannot open {:?}", file_b))`. Of course, it would be better to use proper error handling with `?`. Check out [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow) for a crate that makes error handling really convenient.